# include static JS and CSS WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to include js and css resource files that are local to my project on an html page loaded as a string into a WPF WebBrowser control.

The project builds a dll for a desktop application.  Using Visual Studio 2013 and C#.

The HTML loads in the the WebBrowser, but I get errors related to including the JS file.

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string page = GetPage();
        if (page != null)
        {
            string resourcePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("Resources/");

            //  Try setting an absolute path
            page = page.Replace("Resources/", resourcePath);
            this.webbrowser.NavigateToString(page);
        }
    }
```

Embedded within the html string is the following:

```
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="Resources/myscript.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/mystyle.css"> 
</head>
```

I get an error popup like:

```
An error has occurred in the script on this page.

URL:  aboutC:\MyDir\MyProject\bin\Debug\Resources/myscript.js
```

It prepends "about" to the URL.  I probably also need to change the slashes.
I tried a number of things.  "about" is always prepended.

Also tried using IsolatedStorage, but that doesn't work for my project:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff431811(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use absolute URIs when calling `NavigateToString`.  Since you are not, IE assumes `about:` as the relative path to cause it to fail.

Either [use `file:///C:\some\path.css`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546419/convert-file-path-to-a-file-uri), [`res://somedll.dll/path.css`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292295/accessing-resources-in-registered-net-dll-via-res-protocol), or [host a HTTP server using WCF](https://delog.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/serving-static-web-content-from-a-wcf-service/) on a random high port and use `http://localhost:37458/path.css`.